# SQL pivot not handling absence of data

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table

```
Create table dbo.temp(ID int, ExpenseID int, ExpenseName Varchar(100) null, ExpenseDate date null, Value decimal(19,4) null)
  Insert into dbo.temp values(1,100,'CostClothes','2015-01-01',100.0000)
  Insert into dbo.temp values(1,200,'Discount','2015-01-01',1.0000)

  Insert into dbo.temp values(2,100,'CostClothes','2016-01-01',250.0000)
  Insert into dbo.temp values(2,200,'Discount','2016-01-01',1.0000)

  Insert into dbo.temp values(1,100,'CostClothes','2014-01-01',500.0000)
  Insert into dbo.temp values(2,200,'Discount','2014-01-01',5.0000)
```

Now I want to pivot this table on ExpenseID and the expected output is

```
Create table dbo.output(ID int, CostClothes decimal(19,4) null, Discount  decimal(19,4) null, ExpenseDate date null)
  insert into dbo.output values (1,100.0000,1.0000,'2015-01-01')
  insert into dbo.output values (1,500.0000,NULL,'2014-01-01')
  insert into dbo.output values (2,NULL,5.0000,'2014-01-01')  
  insert into dbo.output values (2,100.0000,1.0000,'2016-01-01')
```

This is what I have and i am not getting correct output

```
SELECT ID,ISNULL([100],0) as CostClothes,ISNULL([200],0) as Discount,expenseDate
  FROM
  (
  SELECT * FROM dbo.temp
  ) AS p 
  PIVOT
  (
    MAX(Value) for ExpenseID in ([100],[200])
  ) AS PV1
```

How do I change the query

Thanks
MR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the sample data, you can either do a pivot with an aggregation, or just a simple conditional aggregation.

```
select
    ID
    ,max(case when ExpenseName = 'CostClothes' then Value end) as CostClothes
    ,max(case when ExpenseName = 'Discount' then Value end) as Discount
    ,ExpenseDate
from
    dbo.temp
group by
    ID
    ,ExpenseDate
order by
    ID
```

**Pivot Method**

```
select
    ID
    ,CostClothes = max(CostClothes)
    ,Discount = max(Discount)
    ,ExpenseDate
from
    dbo.temp
pivot(
    max(Value) for ExpenseName in (CostClothes, Discount)
) p
group by
    ID
    ,ExpenseDate
order by
    ID
```

**Demo:** http://rextester.com/ENHTIK13664

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're selecting too much information in your derived table.

If you're going to use `Select *`, you don't even need a derived table.  When using a `PIVOT`, you should select only the fields you need in your final result.  The same way you would write the conditional aggregation query.

```
SELECT ID,
       ISNULL([100], 0) AS CostClothes,
       ISNULL([200], 0) AS Discount,
       expenseDate
FROM
(
    SELECT ID,
           ExpenseID,
           ExpenseDate,
           Value
    FROM   temp
) AS p PIVOT(MAX(Value) FOR ExpenseID IN([100],[200])) AS PV1
```

This should give you the result you want by eliminating the `ExpenseName` column.  Or you could use the `ExpenseName` column and eliminate the `ExpenseID` column